# Remove last call from Call Log OR keep it from being stored on Android

Tags: android

Things are simple, with a Broadcast receiver I intercept the phone call. Because calling broadcast can't be aborted, the InCallScreen appears and the call get's stored in Call Log. I manged somehow to block the InCallScreen from appearing now I need to do something about the call log. So, I've got the phone number and the date of the call. How do I delete it from the Call log ? If I get the list of items from the Call Log uri, my call will always be the first in that list ?

Comment: Alin i want to know how can delete last call from call log, i know that how can remove all number from call log, but I want remove just one call, can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution was to start a service in the broadcast receiver, after the call state becomes ide. This service will have a sleep time of 5 seconds, time needed to make sure Android inserted the call into call log, and just then query the call log to get info about all calls.